# Getting a no such file or directory error when using --from=MAVEN_BUILD in my Dockerfile

Tags: docker, maven, dockerfile

```
# first stage of our build will use a maven 3.9.1 parent image
FROM maven:3.9.1-ibmjava-8 AS MAVEN_BUILD

# copy the pom and src code to the container
WORKDIR demoapp/util
COPY src ./src
COPY pom.xml .

# package our application code
RUN mvn clean package

# second stage of our build will use ibmjava
FROM ibmjava:8

# copy only the artifacts we need from the first stage and discard the rest
WORKDIR demoapp/util
COPY --from=MAVEN_BUILD target/app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar app/app.jar

# set the startup command to execute the jar
CMD ["java", "-jar", "/app.jar"]
```

With my Dockerfile above, I am getting this error -

```
 => ERROR [stage-1 3/3] COPY --from=MAVEN_BUILD target/app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar app/app.jar                                                                                            0.0s 
------
 > [stage-1 3/3] COPY --from=MAVEN_BUILD target/app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar app/app.jar:
------
Dockerfile:17
--------------------
  15 |     # copy only the artifacts we need from the first stage and discard the rest
  16 |     WORKDIR demoapp/util
  17 | >>> COPY --from=MAVEN_BUILD target/app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar app/app.jar
  18 |
  19 |     # set the startup command to execute the jar
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: failed to compute cache key: failed to calculate checksum of ref moby::vhx6xkubkhu7lciqowjbluqh2: failed to walk /var/lib/docker/tmp/buildkit-mount2407693677/target: lstat /var/lib/docker/tmp/buildkit-mount2407693677/target: no such file or directory
```

But it I remove the `--from=MAVEN_BUILD`, the build will be successful. I have tried to search for a similar encounters and still couldn't figure it out.

Here is the build command that I use,

```
docker build -t app:1.0-SNAPSHOT .
```

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: It may be your antivirus not being done yet.